# unable to add HTML (input and radio button) using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am tring to add an extra input text field and couple of radio buttons to the existing form/HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/5uto80eu/

Please check the above link. It works perfeclty the way I wanted on the jsfiddle site. However, when i am doing same thing on my website its doesnt work at all.

I tried replacing the html in the var ExtraNameSearch and var ExtentionsRadio with something simple, like "

test

"  and it works fine but when 
I try to add the html I want to display. It doesnt work.

Any suggestions.

the code is

```
<div class="">
<form action="/" method="GET"  onsubmit="return checkInput(this)">
<input name="gle" type="hidden" value="namecheck" />
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="packtwo" />
<input class="InputText" id="children_name" name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Enter your children name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your children name'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your children name'"/>
<input class="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Script is

```
// Add the assets for the namecheck thing
$("#children_name").parent().addClass("Add-Ext-Radio")
function addNameCheckAssets (){
// add and extra search input field 
var ExtraNameSearch = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"name\" name=\"nameholder\" placeholder=\"Enter your children name\" onfocus=\"this.placeholder = ''\" onblur=\"this.placeholder = 'Enter your children name'\" onfocus=\"this.placeholder = ''\" onblur=\"this.placeholder = 'Enter your children name'\"/>";
// add radio buttons for extention selection
var ExtentionsRadio = "<div id='extention-selection'> <span class='extention-radio'>  <input type='radio' id='single' name='childrentype' value='male'> <span>Male</span></span>      |     <span class='extention-radio'><input type='radio' id='single' name='childrentype' value='female'><span>Female</span></span></div>";

// insert the assets
$(ExtraNameSearch).insertAfter( "#children_name" );

// add an ID to the form tag to differentiate
$("#children_name").parent().addClass("Add-Ext-Radio")
$(ExtentionsRadio).insertAfter( "form.Add-Ext-Radio" );
}
// Run addNameCheckAssets function
addNameCheckAssets();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap code with `$(document).ready(function() { ...your code... });`

Comment: try debugging in chrome using dev tools (f12) 3 things you can start with: 1.check for errors in console. 2.place breakpoints and check line by line   3. enter console.log statements in your code and check the console as it runs

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was i was loading the script using the content editor and so some reason it was not liking the \" and remove it \.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @CodeToad. I was using the firebug for the same thing but its wasnt fiving anything. will try Chrome next time.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is perfectly same as jsfiddle, the only reason I can imagine is:

**You didn't link the jQuery Library into your HTML.**

Comment: this is a comment **not** an answer

Comment: Well somebody may make the same mistake (actually I did most the time). You think this solution is not hard enough to be an answer and I think I am stupid because I did make the mistake before. But if this is the truth, then that should be an answer.

Comment: Let's just say that it is some kind of guessing. And problem can also be either due to `document.ready` or simple syntax error somewhere else in code (if there is any other code). The idea is to determine type of problem in comments and then to post correct solution as answer. Will you delete your answer if it is incorrect one?

Comment: Will you delete your answer if it is incorrect one? Yes, I will.

Comment: That might be the case, but the OP can always ask you to make your comment into an answer later.

Comment: thanks guys, I have liked the jQuery to my HTML, hoever I actually missed the document.ready.

Comment: but the problem is still there, I think there might a syntax error some were on the file. unfortunatly the code is not online so i cannot provide the link but thanks for the help.